TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status') at conn
I am trying to connect to database but it is showing the error .....but here's the twist. If i start the whole code from  start it is working fine but if i re-open my code editor it is throwing this error
Here's the code :
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const conn = async() => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:<password>@cluster0.mongodb.net/");  //removed the passowrd 
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Not Connected", error);
    }
};

conn();

Can any one help me with this ...
I tried to connect to database ...
I should be connected successfully

Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace

Also could you share the version of the installed npm packages?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
